# What is the path of Windows directory

Tags: excel, vba

I need to access the Windows directory in my project. How can I get the Windows path? I mean how can I get the path, where Windows is installed?

Comment: `Environ("windir")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "environ" function to retrieve the directory, as I show below:

```
Dim windowsDir As String
windowsDir = Environ("windir")
```